# for loop in bash with two files, iterate filenames

Tags: bash, for-loop, iteration

I am trying to process multiple files in a bash for loop, and need to pull in two different files per run. 
An example of the input data I have is:

```
temperature1985.nc
maskfile1985.nc
temperature1986.nc
maskfile1986.nc
...
```

The command I would use for single runs (given that the working folder only contains the wanted files) would be:

```
cdo mul infile1 infile2 outfile
```

and I have tried this to automate the runs:

```
for ((i=1985; i <= 30; i++));

do printf "cdo mul temperature%04d.nc maskfile%04.nc ${i%.nc}_mul.nc” $i;

done,
```

...where cdo mul is an external script, and infile1 = temperature1985.nc; infile2 = maskfile1985.nc and the name of the outfile name should be equal to e.g. infile1 with an added stamp, e.g. "_mul"

The automation will not output a correct file. I have tried to read through similar examples, but I have not found a similar example which could help me further. Any inputs on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: what is your problem? I notice a non-ascii `”` in your code.

Comment: 1985 > 30, so your loop never runs. You want `i <= 1985+30`.

Answer (score 0):

To read 2 lines in a loop:

```
produce_your_input_data | paste - - | while read -r firstfile secondfile; do 
    cdo mul "$firstfile" "$secondfile" "${firstfile%.nc}_mul.nc"
done
```

or

```
produce_your_input_data | while read -r firstfile && read -r secondfile; do ...
```